# Get Orders with single line with specific status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a query for purchase order data. Orders contain a header table (`PS_PO_HDR`) and a corresponding Lines table (`PS_PO_LINE`) that are joined by `BUSINESS_UNIT` and `PO_ID`. There can be 1 or more lines of a `PO_I`D that map to 1 `PO_ID` on the header table. I need a query that will identify `PO_ID`'s that only have only either a single line (or another way put `PO_ID`'s with no more than 1 line) with a `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'` **OR** multiple lines that all have `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'`, along with the other criteria below. I've tried a combination of `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but the below query will pick up PO_ID's with multiple lines where one of those lines has `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'`. That is not what I need, I need to identify `PO_ID`'s from the `PS_PO_LINE` table that only have a single row (1 line).

```
SELECT LINE.PO_ID, COUNT(LINE.PO_ID), COUNT(LINE.CANCEL_STATUS)
FROM PS_PO_LINE LINE
INNER JOIN PS_PO_HDR HEADER ON HEADER.BUSINESS_UNIT = LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT AND HEADER.PO_ID = LINE.PO_ID
WHERE 
HEADER.PO_DT >= '01-JAN-2019'
 AND HEADER.PO_STATUS NOT IN ('C', 'X', 'PX')
 AND LINE.CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'
GROUP BY LINE.PO_ID
HAVING COUNT(LINE.PO_ID) = 1 AND COUNT(LINE.CANCEL_STATUS) = 1
```

Example data: Below is an example from the `PS_PO_LINE` table. This is ordered by `BUSINESS_UNIT` and `PO_ID`. The Green highlighted row (`PO_ID` A030010686) is a `PO_ID` with only 1 line (row) that has `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'`. You can see the other `PO_ID`'s A030010688 and L010006793 each does have a row with `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'` but it also contains an additional with a different `CANCEL_STATUS` value (A) so I would not want these included in my results. I only want to return `PO_ID`'s that have 1 or more lines that **all** have `CANCEL_STATUS = 'X'` (with the other criteria above).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this (return all HEADER.PO_ID with one or more LINES all with LINE.CANCEL_STATUS = 'X' AND HEADER.PO_DT >= '01-JAN-2019'):

```
SELECT HEADER.PO_ID
FROM PS_PO_HDR HEADER
INNER JOIN PS_PO_LINE LINE ON HEADER.BUSINESS_UNIT = LINE.BUSINESS_UNIT AND HEADER.PO_ID = LINE.PO_ID
WHERE HEADER.PO_DT >= '01-JAN-2019'
GROUP BY HEADER.PO_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN LINE.CANCEL_STATUS = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

You need to GROUP BY for all HEADER (table) fields part of the primary key, so if BUSINESS_UNIT is part of the primary key add it to GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

Probably many better ways of doing it - but I suggest labelling each PO_ID with markers up front - the common table expression linesAndStates below can then be used to cherry pick required conditions later

```
with cte_linesAndStates as (
select line.PO_ID
     , TotalLines = count(line.PO_ID)
     , LineCancelStatusX = sum(case when line.cancel_status in ('X') 
                                    then 1 else 0 end)
     , LineCancelStatusNotX = sum(case when line.cancel_status not in ('X') 
                                     then 1 else 0 end)
  from ps_po_line line
  group by line.PO_ID
)
SELECT header.Business_Unit
     , line.PO_ID
     , line.line_nbr
     , line.cancel_status
  FROM PS_PO_LINE LINE
  inner join cte_linesAndStates on cte_linesAndStates.po_id = ps_po_line.po_id
     and (cte_linesAndStates.LineCancelStatusX > 0   -- Explicitly asking for X
     and cte_linesAndStates.LineCancelStatusNotX = 0)  -- Explicitly excluding non X
     --- insert other critieria here with OR AND etc
  inner join ps_po_hdr header 
     on header.business_unit = line.business_unit and header.po_id = line.po_id
 where header.po_dt >= '01-jan-2019'
   and header.po_status not in ('C', 'X', 'PX')
```